# Compute the Riesz measure of the $\log|z|$ function is the Dirac Mass at 0

Tags: complex-analysis, distribution-theory

If $u$ is a subharmonic function,
$$\mu_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \Delta u$$ is defined as the Riesz measure of $u$. Let $u(z)=\log |z|$, prove that
$$
\mu_u = \frac{1}{2\pi} \Delta \log|u| = \delta_0 = \text{Dirac Mass at 0}
$$

When I tried to compute the laplacian directly, the results did not seem to be anything close to the definition of Dirac Mass at 0. I am not that familiar with the distribution theory, how do I approach this question?

Comment: Sounds good.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi \in \mathbb{S}$ and $u=\log(|\vec \rho|)$.  Then using polar coordinates, we have

$$\begin{align}
\langle \Delta u, \phi\rangle &=\langle u,\Delta \phi\rangle\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty\log(\rho)\Delta \phi(\vec \rho)\,\rho\,d\rho\,d\theta\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \nabla \cdot \left(\log(\rho)\nabla u(\vec \rho)\right)-\nabla \left(\log(\rho)\right)\cdot \nabla \left(u(\vec \rho)\right)\,\rho\,d\rho\,d\theta\\\\
&=-\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial u(\vec \rho)}{\partial \rho}\,d\rho\,d\theta\\\\
&=2\pi u(0)
\end{align}$$

Hence, we see that in distribution $\frac1{2\pi}\Delta \log(\vec \rho)=\delta(\vec \rho)$.  And we are done!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't quite get the third and the fourth equality. I tried to write out the terms using product rule of the gradient but failed to get the equality. Is there a trick that I don't know about? Could you elaborate more? Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  For the third equality we used the product rule for the divergence (i.e., $ \nabla \cdot (\phi \vec A)=\nabla \phi \cdot \vec A+\phi \nabla \cdot \vec A$).  Here $\vec A=\nabla u$ and $\phi = \log(\rho)$.

Comment: @Tab1e To arrive at the fourth line, we used the $2$-D Divergence Theorem and exploited the fact that $u$ is smooth and has compact support.

Comment: I see, so we obtain the conclusion from the fact that the integral gives back the function itself at 0, which is the definition of the Dirac mass at 0?

Comment: Technically, it is not an integral.  It is a distribution.  But heuristically speaking, then yes.  The distribution $\frac1{2\pi}\Delta u$ is equivalent to the distribution $\delta_0$

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Pleased to hear.  And you're welcome.